# How to use gzbuilder with ROS?

Tags: ros, gazebo, gazebo-worlds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to create a terrain map that can be used in Gazebo. I have a ROS version of the Gazebo plugin. After some basic search, I found that "gzbuilder" is the utility that needs to be used to create terrain maps compatible within Gazebo. This gzbuilder utility is usually shipped (I presume) within a Gazebo source install for Ubuntu. However, I cannot find it within the ROS installation of the same. Could someone, please tell me how I can use gzbuilder if I have Gazebo for ROS installed? Alternatively, if you know how to create terrain maps for Gazebo, I would appreaciate that.
Thank you,
Ammar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47211/how-to-use-gzbuilder-with-ros?/) by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 289 on 2012-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I figured it out. GzBuilder has been deprecated. Though Gazebo can accept COLLADA (.dae files). Therefore I just used MeshBuilder and converted the GeoTiff files that I had into .dae and was able to load it in Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [Ammar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2639/ammar/) with karma: 289 on 2012-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0